# Create a fast rolling sum over a 2D array with different windows per item

Tags: arrays, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numba

I need to compute the rolling sum on a 2D array with different windows for each element.
(The sum can also go forward or backward.)

I made a function, but it is too slow (I need to call it hundreds or even thousands of times).

Here is my current function

```
def rolling_sum(ar, window, direction="forward"):
    ar_sum = ar.copy().astype(float) #By default with start with window of 1.
    for w in np.unique(window):
        if w > 1: #Formula doesn't work if w == 1
            mask = (window == w) #Elements matching this window
            if direction=="forward":
                ar_sum[mask,:-w+1] += sum([ar[mask,col:ar.shape[1]+1-w+col] for col in range(1, w)])
                ar_sum[mask,-w+1:] = np.nan #Undefined
            elif direction=="backward":
                ar_sum[mask,w-1:] += sum([ar[mask,w-1-col:ar.shape[1]-col] for col in range(1, w)])
                ar_sum[mask,:w-1] = np.nan #Undefined
    # Correction if window = 0
    mask = window == 0
    ar_sum[mask] = 0
    return ar_sum
```

And here is my test setup

```
ar = np.random.randint(-100, 100, size=(10000, 50))
window = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=(10000))
rolling_sum(ar, window, direction="forward")
```

Comment: The fast sliding window code in `stride_tricks` only works for one window size.

Comment: You should really avoid the pattern `np.unique(window)` + `window == w`. This is not algorithmically efficient on large inputs with several unique values (because of a quadratic execution). Consider using a group-by approach. Numpy does not provide ways to do that easily/efficiently but this can be done in Numba manually.

Comment: Thank you, Jerome, for your idea. On my typical dataset, we shouldn't have more than a few different windows.